# str object has no attribute get

Tags: python, mysql, tkinter

I am creating a connection with mysql through tkinter. I have to enter date values in the entry and store it in the database. This is the code

```
def dynamic_data_entry():
    unix=int(time.time())
    date=str(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(unix).strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
    keyword="python"
    value=random.randrange(0,10)
    bname=StringVar()
    auth=StringVar()
    reiss=StringVar()
    gen=StringVar()
    libcur.execute("insert into libarius(Book_Name,Author,DOI,DOR,Re_issues,Genre) values (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)", (bname.get(),auth.get(),date.get(),date.get(),reiss.get(),gen.get()))
    libcur.close()
    libcur.commit()
```

But i get the following error

```
runfile('C:/Users/sapna/Desktop/SAMARTH.py', wdir='C:/Users/sapna/Desktop')
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\sapna\anaconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\sapna\Desktop\SAMARTH.py", line 64, in dynamic_data_entry
    libcur.execute("insert into libarius(Book_Name,Author,DOI,DOR,Re_issues,Genre) values (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)", (bname.get(),auth.get(),date.get(),date.get(),reiss.get(),gen.get()))
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'
```

How do i solve this problem
thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have `date.get()` but `date` is a string, not a `StringVar`. You don't need to call `get()` to get its value.

```
    libcur.execute("insert into libarius(Book_Name,Author,DOI,DOR,Re_issues,Genre) values (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)", 
        (bname.get(),auth.get(),date,date,reiss.get(),gen.get()))
```

BTW, you never use the `keyword` or `value` variables.

And the `commit()` method should be executed on the connection object, not the cursor.